# Reducing lines of jQuery code, unnecessary repetition

Tags: jquery

I am hoping to be able to reduce the repetition in the following code, which changes an image source and also the background image of a div when you click a numbered link.

I was thinking that since I numbered the variables and selectors in the same way (1, 2, 3...) I could rewrite the click function part in less lines to avoid having to change this every time I change the number of images? Maybe the click function could get its own class (eg 2) and apply it to the other lines?

Images (can be any number)

```
var image1 = 'Home.jpg';
var image2 = 'About.jpg';
var image3 = 'Contact.jpg';
```

Click function (currently repeats to cover all images above)

```
$('.1').click(function() {
   $("#image").attr('src', image1);
   $('#center').css('background', 'url(' +  image1 + ') no-repeat center top');
});
$('.2').click(function() {
   $("#image").attr('src', image2);
   $('#center').css('background', 'url(' +  image2 + ') no-repeat center top');
});
$('.3').click(function() {
   $("#image").attr('src', image3);
   $('#center').css('background', 'url(' +  image3 + ') no-repeat center top');
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="1">Option 1</a>
<a href="#" class="2">Option 2</a>
<a href="#" class="3">Option 3</a>
```

You can see the code in action here: http://carolineelisa.com/zack/

Any suggestions for making this smaller and easier to update would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just a warning: you will run into problems if you begin your class names with a numerical character

Comment: Hi @Muleskinner, is that just problems with styling via CSS? I am only using numbers in this case to trigger the jQuery functions, not to apply styles.

Comment: I am not sure - might work - but anyway I would go far to avoid it as it is invalid due to the specifications. You never know when or where it will break

Comment: You could just append a string before the number: `class="option1"` and change your selector to `$('.option' + imageIndex)`.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Owen, I will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var images = ['Home.jpg', 'About.jpg', 'Contact.jpg'];

$.each(images, function(index, image) {
  var imageIndex = index + 1; 
  $('.' + imageIndex).click(function() {
    $("#image").attr('src', image);
    $('#center').css('background', 'url(' +  image + ') no-repeat center top');
  });
});
```

You might want to call `$.append()` as well to dynamically create the HTML for each image before you attach the click handler. If you chose to generate the HTML server side then you will need to find a way to avoid duplicating the images array on both the client-side and server-side.

Comment: That looks more like it! But for some reason it is not picking up the first image (is that because it is 0?), so 1A(1) is displaying 1B(2), 1B(2) is displaying 2A(3) and so on: http://carolineelisa.com/zack/jquery.html

Comment: Sorry, you're right about the zero-based index. I've modified the answer to add 1 before setting the class.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   //Should get the class-numbers of the clicked link:
   var number = $(this).attr('class');

   $("#image").attr('src', image+class);
   $('#center').css('background', 'url(' +  image+class + ') no-repeat center top');
});
```